# How to do some calculation between Columns in spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark

For example, I want to plus the la and lon column and output result in another column.

```
+------+------------------+------------------+
|userid|               la |               lon|
+------+------------------+------------------+
|    u3|               2.0|               2.0|
|    u4|               1.0|               1.0|
|    u5|               2.0|               2.0|
|    u1|1.6666666666666667|2.6666666666666665|
|    u6|               1.0|               3.5|
|    u2|               3.0|               4.0|
+------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the calculation you want and what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to sum two columns together, it's pretty straightforward :

```
df.withColumn("x", $"la" + $"lon")
```

x is the name of the new column.

To elevate the column into the power of 2 :

```
df.withColumn("x", pow($"la" + $"lon", 2))
```

Comment: Why I get error when I do df.withColumn("x", pow($"la" + $"lon"))?  Error:(407, 30) could not find implicit value for parameter impl: breeze.numerics.pow.Impl[org.apache.spark.sql.Column,VR]
    result.withColumn("x",pow($"la1"-$"la2")).show()
                             ^

Comment: You are elevating by the power of what ?

Comment: I just want to output ($"la" + $"lon")^2, how to do it?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please for further questions try writing the whole question in one time and also add what you have tried !

Comment: How to achieve this in Java? I want to do `1 + log(<col1>)*log(<col2>/100)`